# Receiving POST data with Express.js sent by angular2 app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have following code on Node.js:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
```

But it appears that req object does not have body property.

With angular2 I am sending **stringified JSON** with **Content-Type:application/json**

Angular code looks like this:

```
this.http.post(
  "http://url.com",
  JSON.stringify(data_obj), {headers:{'Content-Type': 
  'application/json'}}).subscribe((res:Response) => this.extractData(res));
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any middleware installed in the express server? Say: express [bodyparser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)?

Comment: No, node says that this middleware is no longer bundled with express and must be installed separately

Comment: yea, but you still need to parse body like @Gimby mentioned.

Comment: Ok, clear thanks a lot

Comment: However I could not find in req object any field/value from posted data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NodeJS application does not have [bodyParser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) so it is unable to parse the body of the request. Do this in your NodeJS application

**Install body-parser**

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

**Add to nodeJS app**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the body parser middleware in your app:

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

you can install it with this command: `npm install body-parser --save`

for example you can write this code to your main file:

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

This is a basic configuration for the body parser middleware, it parse POST parameters into req.body.

If you want to learn more about the configurations of body parser, read the associate doc into the github repo.